# MySql server "Error No. 2003 Can't connect to Mysql server", no me puedo conectar, ya he cambiado my.cnf y creado usuarios remotos ayuda por favor

Tags: mysql, debian, google-cloud-platform

Necesito ayuda chicos, mi servidor se está ejecutando en la plataforma Google Cloud, voy a dejar las especificaciones aquí:

versión de mysql: Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.26-MariaDB, para debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) usando readline 5.2

El archivo de configuración de MySql se encuentra en "/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf"

Ya he cambiado la línea de "bind-address = 127.0.0.1" a
  "bind-address = 0.0.0.0" después de eso reinicié el servicio con "sudo mysql service restart"

luego creé usuarios y permití conexiones remotas, aquí hay una lista de mis usuarios

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado conectarme a través del cliente sqlyog, pero sigue arrojando el mismo mensaje de error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguien por favor ayuda):

Comment: Traduce la pregunta el idioma oficial es el **Español**

Comment: traducela, estas en la versión en español de SO

Comment: Listo, una disculpa, creí que estaba en la versión en inglés

Comment: Veo que `myuser` tiene el host `%` asignado. ¿Por qué no pruebas con alguno de los usuarios que tienen `localhost`?

Comment: Los usuarios que tienen el @localhost me sirven para conectarme directamente desde el server, en esos si puedo entrar, pero desde el mismo servidor, yo quiero conectarme remotamente desde mi pc, con sqlyog

Comment: ¿habilitastes el puerto 3306 a tu vps???, recuerda que si utilizas una instancia aparte de mysql en Google Cloud esta lo tiene por defecto, pero el VPS no, alli tienes que permitir los accesos, por otro lado recuerda que no solo debes permitir a los usuarios si no tambien la IP que tiene permitido acceder a tu base de datos, puyedes probar estos pasos a ver: [Acceso remoto](https://geekytheory.com/como-permitir-el-acceso-remoto-a-una-base-de-datos-mysql), yo en lo personal tengo un VPS y una instancia a parte de MySQL lo que garantiza más rapidez y menos costes al no escalar el VPS

Comment: Igual recomiendo que el archivo my.cnf configures las IPs que tienen acceso a tu MySQL, asi incrementas la seguridad

Comment: Muchas gracias muchachos, pero ya fue resuelto este problema, lo publiqué en la versión en inglés de stackoverflow

Comment: Hola Jorge, bienvenido. Si un usuario llega a esta pregunta con el mismo problema quizá le vendría bien que publiques cómo lo resolviste :-) Un saludo!